# How can I know why exactly my comment was deleted?

Tags: support, questions

This time I just cannot imagine what was wrong with my first comment at:

[Prevent user paste in fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159072/prevent-user-paste-in-fields)

I'm sure deleted/hidden comments are still available for the mods so anyone could explain what I've done wrong

Comment: What was your comment? Care to share?

Comment: Having your comment deleted doesn't necessarily mean you did something wrong, comments are ephemeral by nature, it might just be the case that your comment was obsolete. Strictly speaking, if your comment wasn't about requesting clarifications or about providing _constructive_ criticism, you shouldn't have posted it in the first place - see: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment

Comment: @Bart: Something like "It's very, very, very, very bad idea"

Comment: @zerkms Mwah, most likely under the header "not constructive" I guess. Possibly flagged. Some might find it noise if you don't qualify that comment. Not something I would flag, but well... Anyway, just a guess. I can't see the comment, nor its possible flags. :)

Comment: @Bart: I'm wondering then why such useful comment has been flagged and deleted, and the whole question (which is just silly) wasn't :-S I don't want to live on this planet anymore

Comment: @zerkms Haha, well, if comment deletion is the biggest problem you have, then you have a pretty sweet life. ;)

Comment: @zerkms `I don't want to live on this planet anymore` May I suggest moving to Mars? The climate is excellent this time of the year...

Comment: @Yannis Rizos: that's a good alternative, actually. At least I would have the better and cheaper internet connection than I have now (New Zealand)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this was the gist of your comment:

> It's very, very, very, very bad idea

What good is it? Explain ***why*** you think the idea is bad next time, the comment probably got flagged because it sounds rude and is extremely unhelpful.

If a few users flag your comment, it gets zapped. That doesn't mean you did something wrong, it just means part of the community thought it was better of being removed.

> I'm wondering then why such useful comment has been flagged and deleted, and the whole question (which is just silly) wasn't

That's just like, your opinion man.

The question isn't necessarily silly, I've had issues with people copy/pasting generated temporary passwords before, and they copy too much (make a mistake) and end up emailing me for support when it doesn't work, which is annoying. In that case, I prefer to make them type it.

Comment: Despite the irony, I purged all of the comments on this answer. Why? Because they completely degenerated into arguing about semantics. The only suggestion worth preserving is "if you believe your comment is providing a valuable warning to the asker, turn it into an answer". Comments have always been second-class citizens on the network. If all else fails and you absolutely believe your comment deserves to stay, just post it again. It might get flagged again or it might not. But make sure you're commenting for the right reasons - to teach something, not just to toss out an off-the-cuff opinion.

Comment: @AnnaLear But now I need a meta-meta to ask why my comments were deleted.

Comment: @DaveNewton Even worse. I now have to ask why my comments were paraphrased. Tsk tsk tsk.